# Remote Database Managemnet

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am looking for a .Net Web Application to manage a Sql Server 2005 database, i am thinking something along the lines of phpmyadmin.

Note : My current hosting provider does not provide any management interface or allow direct connections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of web tools that will do this such as this one from microsoft:
[Microsoft Sql Web Manager](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=c039a798-c57a-419e-acbc-2a332cb7f959&displaylang=en)

or this one (commercial as far as I know):
[My Little Admin](http://mylittleadmin.com/en/welcome.aspx)

Comment: I have tried my little admin , but as you said its commercial and i dont bring enough to justify using that.